# Simple search function return always 0 results

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$likeString = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_caption LIKE ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $likeString);
$query->execute();

    var_dump($likeString);
    if (!$query) {
      printf("Query failed: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
      exit;
    }   
    if($res->num_rows > 0) {
       while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {          
             echo "<br>Title: " . $row['image_caption'];          
       }
    } else { 
          echo " <br> 0 results"; 
    }

}
```

`var_dump($likeString)` shows the word which I've posted via search form correctly. Also I've tried in phpmyadmin directly to run this query

> SELECT * 
>   FROM images
>   WHERE image_caption LIKE  "%Volvo%"

And I've received 1 result which is correct. On page I see `0 results`. Tried to play with fetch:

```
$res->fetch_assoc()
$res->fetchAll()
$res->fetch()
```

none of them show any result. I'm sure is something very silly and simple mistake but can't see it. Please help on this.

I don't have `Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` It was my mistake while I've made proposed changes from one of the answer. Problem still remains - **0 Results**

UPDATE: Current code

```
$likeString = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_caption LIKE ? ");
$query->bind_param('s', $likeString);
$query->execute();

    if($query->num_rows > 0) {
       while ($row = $query->fetch()) {          
             echo "<br>Title: " . $row['image_caption'];          
       }
    } else { 
          echo " <br> 0 results"; 
    }

}
```

UPDATE 2: DB connection checked-> result is `Connected successfully`

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mydbUsername"; // it's changed for the question
$password = "myPass"; // it's changed for the question
$dbname = "myDbName"; // it's changed for the question

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: Replcae this two lines : $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_caption LIKE %".$_POST['search']."%");
//$query->bind_param('s', $likeString);

Comment: Error: `Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`

Comment: The var *$res* is not defined in your so `$res->num_rows > 0` is *false*

Comment: Question is not duplicate.. I don't have this error.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_caption LIKE "%Volvo%"` did u tried in phpmyadmin? check the result, and also check your connection

Comment: @devpro yes, it is in my question.. `SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_caption LIKE "%Volvo%" And I've received 1 result which is correct`

Comment: alright, check your connection using mysqli or PDO?

Comment: @devpro mysqli. Added to question my connection too.

Comment: alright, means your connection is working fine, now last debugging, use `SELECT * FROM images` query in your code, and chk the result.. if its fine than we can move our focus on WHERE clause.

Comment: @devpro strange but still shows 0 results..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128036/discussion-between-devpro-and-jason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this : (update your code)

```
$likeString= "%{$_POST['search']}%";
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_caption LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $likeString);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        foreach ($row as $r)
        {
           echo "<br>Title: " . $r['image_caption'];                
        }
        print "\n";
    }
```

OR

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli("localhost","mydbUsername","myPass","myDbName");
  /* check connection */
  if ($conn->connect_errno) { 
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error); 
    exit(); 
  }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_caption LIKE %".$_POST['search']."%";

  if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> Title: ". $row["image_caption"]);
    }print "\n";

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
  }

  /* close connection */
  $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: it should be this `$param` instead of this `$likeString`.

Comment: What is the difference? Only the brackets on `$_POST['search']`? Still no results..

Comment: try with above update , maybe helpful (not much sure)

Comment: Thanks but still no results.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `$res` while it is not defined... You must use `$query` instead.
Next time turn on error reporting to see such silly bugs

Comment: Still `0 Results`. I have added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `error_reporting(0);` at the top.. no errors

Comment: error_reporting(0) blocks displaying errors. You must set E_ALL and ini_set('display_errors', 'On')

Comment: You are not getting 0 results. You have an if statement with a condition that is false because you are using a variable `$res` which does not have a value, you then echo that you have 0 results.

Comment: @nospor Was commenting to Jason because he indicated "Still 0 Results."  I should have used the person tags in my comment.

Comment: @varlogtim I've changed variable to `$query` still `0 results`. I've edited my question with current source